# WORDPRESS: My categories page, show an empty page

Tags: wordpress

when I navigate through my website the category link works great, but when I copy/paste the URL, it shows an empty page.

This happens only on category/subcategories URLs.

My permalink structure is that: /%category%/%postname%/

(The theme is a custom developed theme by me, and it is not uploaded yet to my hosting server, so it runs locally for now)

Comment: have to compared the both links?

Comment: the links are exaclty the same, as I copy/paste them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that 'Yoast SEO Plugin' caused the issue, when I checked the strip '/category/' from url. So the issue is now solved by unchekng this option in yoast plugin. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

@elis - You should go back into Yoast and try to turn that setting on. Once you've done that, go through and flush out your rewrite rules.

1. Step 1: In the main menu find "Settings > Permalinks".

   Step 2: Scroll down if needed and click "Save Changes".

   Step 3: Rewrite rules and permalinks are flushed.